# How to view the sqlite tables and its columns?

Tags: android, sqlite

We are working on android project and it is storing the data in sqlite database. We have downloaded that android application and executed successfully. But now the problem is when we had gone through the database files we were unable to find the table names in it. Can you please tell us how to know what are the tables existing and their column names in sqlite database? After knowing them we need to connect our sqlite database to remote database.

```
     Please help us with this problem.
```

Thanks,

Comment: you have to execute single select command

Comment: If you want to see the database file and database table in that file visually, then I would suggest you to use sqlite browser, it is a free tool and you can easily download it. I have found it very helpful while debugging. You will have to pull your database file from your project and then open it with this browser.

Answer (score 1):

> your question is just like view table and its content. so i prefer to you that use sqlite manager.
>
> for sqlitemanager you need to firefox.
>
> 1. download firefox and open https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
> 2. then go to db file where it located in data/data/com.project/a.db
> 3. click it and push it out & save it.
> 4. go to tool menu in firefox
> 5. click on sqlite manager
> 6. it diplay one IDE
> 7. open those db file and view.